# Database tables for entries of another table?

Tags: java, database, h2

I'm designing a new revision of my Java application (using an embedded H2 database) around a redesign of the way I'll be handling my data.  Here's how I have it planned:

- Entries table-

  - Entry ID
  - Entry name
- Properties table-

  - Property ID
  - Property name
- (Individual property) value table-

  - Value ID
  - Entry ID
  - (Value columns...)
- (Individual entry) value table-

  - Property name
  - (Individual property) value ID

Each entry can have multiple properties (including multiple properties of the same type).  Each property has its own way of storing its values.  I need to look up all properties defined for a given entry, and maybe all entries for each given property.

Is this a good way to do it?

**Edit:** I'm not sure I explained it well...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, that's a very bad way to model data, but this is a very ivory-tower way of looking at the situation as I haven't had to use this model in practice. By the way, it's called the "Entity-Attribute-Value" approach. And the reason I dislike it is because it's very un-schema-like in that most SQL functionality has to be replicated in some way.

There's definitely a time and a place for it (like if you intend to model many objects that have disparate models) or that have schemas that change frequently. But I personally think it's terrible.

Comment: Yes, I'm wary of what it's going to mean to use it.  Thanks for giving me a name for it.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, I would use intersection or [junction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_table) tables instead of what you described.

So you can create a query to get you all the Properties per Entery, or all the Enteries per Property.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Unknown Google.  This is also called the [Inner-platform effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner-platform_effect).